# Error in deployment of application on glassfish4.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4

When I deploy the war file in glassfish 4.1, the following exception is coming out

> Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
>       java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>         at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
>         at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
>         at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
>         at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>         at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

In my system two java version 1.7 and 1.8 are there for two different projects. Don't know how but glassfish server's java platform version changed from 1.7 to 1.8. After correcting it application deployment was successful.